# How do I scroll my Palm webOS application?

Tags: scroll, webos, palm

This feels like a dumb newbie question.  I'm attempting to follow the [Palm's online tutorial](http://developer.palm.com/index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=1758&Itemid=21) for developing a webOS app.  I ran `palm-generate` and tried updating the generated index.html file to have a body with a bunch of content (the word "HELLO" repeated 400 times).

When I attempt to load that document in the emulator, I find that I'm unable to scroll the screen to read the rest of the text.  I drag the screen, but nothing happens.  The page scrolls just fine in the Palm web browser.

Is there a setting to allow users to drag my app to scroll it?  I see documentation for a Mojo.Widget.Scroller, but that seems like it shouldn't be necessary for a simple web page with a bunch of text on it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to [arthurthornton](http://developer.palm.com/distribution/viewtopic.php?f=11&t=9255#p42976):

> You can take anything that would normally be inside the  tags and put that inside the scene HTML file.
>
> OR you could just make a basic scene with a webview widget inside it that has your site as the source.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, the Scroller widget is needed for scrolling.  The standard WebKit view that's shown in a card has no native scrolling ability, so the Mojo scroller widget implements the logic for displaying more content that can fit.

You can try this out by making a new project in the Ares IDE.  Just add a Scroller and use the Maximize button to make it fill the scene.  Then, add a HTML object to it, and add your HTML content to that object.  You'll then have a nice scene which allows you to scroll through a lot of content.